Banno API Endpoint For 2-step verification
is there an available Banno endpoint for querying a customers 2-step verification configuration which lives under the Security tab of their profile? I am unable to find anything under the Admin or Consumer API references.

There isn't an endpoint available for that specifically.
You may consider looking into the abilities endpoint which will give you some details, but not specifically allow you to configure the 2FA configuration.
